# Open block tag in if statement and close it in another if statement

Tags: php, twig

I'm still figuring out Twig template and I bet I am still trying to know this.
So here is what I am trying to do, but I get "Unexpected "else" tag (expecting closing tag for the "block" tag defined near line 63)."

```
{% if logged_in %}
    {% block one %}
    <div>
{% else %}
    {% block two %}
{% endif %}

{% if logged_in %}
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Can someone explain there is another way to handle this scenario in Twig?
thank you.

Comment: Blocks can't be defined dynamicly

Comment: Is there a way to do that dynamically for the scenario?

Comment: can't you do a different include?